# Entlib5 Validation [IgnoreNull] throws exception while adding objects to list

Tags: c#, validation, enterprise-library, data-annotations

I have a class Partner and I use entlib5 validation block to validate class's fields (using data anottations).
In one of method I read db table and create binding list of Partner's objects, but if there is an [IgnoreNull] annotation or [ValidationComposition]+[NotNullValidator] i get an System.NotSupportedException (for example: A validation attribute of type ValidatorCompositionAttribute cannot be used to validate values.)

If I use only [StringLengthValidator] there isn't any exception (but I need IgnoreNull or similar validator for some fields that can be leaved blank, or string must be within some range)

What is a problem?

Comment: on this thread is solution when [IgnoreNull] and composition+notnull are not needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832973/entlib5-string-validation

Comment: P.S. Unfortunately, I didn't managed to validate field using Compostion.Or + NotNull or IgnoreNulls (this validators works for me only when I bind data from WPF to business logic class)