# Entlib5 string validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, enterprise-library

How can I validate some string if this is the rule:

```
- can be empty
- if not empty -> max length: 30
```

I know this two ways:

```
[IgnoreNulls]
[StringLengthValidator(30)]
```

or

```
[ValidatorComposition(CompositionType.Or)]
[StringLengthValidator(30)] 
[NotNullValidator(Negated=true)]
```

but is there a way NOT to use IgnoreNulls or Composition.Or (have problems: [Entlib5 Validation [IgnoreNull] throws exception while adding objects to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776721/entlib5-validation-ignorenull-throws-exception-while-adding-objects-to-list))

Comment: Composition.And and IgnoreNulls is also NotSupported

SOLVED (it was obvious) : if i set private field like this:private string _address = string.Empty, then [IgnoreNulls] or [ValidationComposition]+[NotNullValidator] are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue. I couldn't use Composition, NotNull or IgnoreNull validators. What I did is:

```
private string _address = string.Empty; // IMPORTANT!

[StringLengthValidator(30, "Max. 30 chars")]
public string Address {
    get { return _address; }
    set { _address = value; }
}
```

Now, in first call field _address is not null, it's empty string and IgnoreNulls annotation is now not needed. StringLengthValidator now checks only if Address is <=30 characters.